# SSO for powerapps portal. Using SAML provider

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps

So the problem here is to make a connection between an identity provider and a portal to provide SSO login between a SAML provider app and a powerapps portal. I am also using a Sign in User Flow in AD B2C(issuer and etc. is filled in a form for IdP in a picture below).
Once you sign in to the provider website which will take you to the selection of multiple portals you can enter. You should be signed in after you select one.
There is the most to see in the following pictures:

[Apps registered in AD B2C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQzss.png)

[Identity provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS7YR.png) information filled in a form.

[Site settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwhVx.png) created in a portal management.

[SAML provider app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOFiA.png) after login view.

[Powerapps portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAC77.png) not signed in after selecting it.

My questions here are:
Am I missing some site settings?
Is there a place to enter some sort of certificate or key which will allow the connection?
Is it possible to be done on side of portal or do I need to contact provider to somehow udjust their code?

Thanks for all advices. If there will be a need for more details do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You have configured SAML 2.0 for portals and there is no specific settings missing on that front. In order to isolate why it is not Signed in after selecting kindly open a support case.